# Use CONCATENATE to return a value from another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Normally, when you link to another cell you get the contents of that cell returned.

What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("=C:/documents/'[",B15,".xls]Sheet 1'!D3"))
```

At the moment, it simply returns the link to the sheet. What I'd like it to do is return the value in the specific cell. Am I on the right track or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the INDIRECT function, I think that is the one you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Use INDIRECT

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("C:/documents/'[",B15,".xls]Sheet 1'!D3"))
```

Comment: does `INDIRECT` work when the source sheet is not opened currently?

Comment: Perhaps. Did it fail when you ran it when the sheet was not opened?

Comment: I read somewhere that indirect does not work when the sheet is closed. Perhaps you can give a try